# Location list in ascending order

Tags: android, search, text, location

I am working on google place API for getting near location list of user's current location. I am succeed in getting the list in particular radius of user's current location. I want this list of location in ascending of distance.So  location which is near to me should be display on top of list. Here is what I have done till now with the use of Google Place Textsearch API.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=real+peprika&key=your_key&location=23.020820000000004,72.57407666666667&radius=50000&rankBy=distance

Here I have used latitude and longitude of my current location. radius is in which I want to search location.And I have also used rankBy=distance for getting list in order of distance but I can not get location in ascending order. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think there is no need for code. I get distance list from above URL which is not in ascending order. can you please tell me what is the problem in this URL? how to get this distance in ascending order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting adapter to listView.

```
Collections.sort(rowItems, new CustomComparator());
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<YOUROBJECTCLASSNAME> {
        @Override
        public int compare(YOUROBJECTCLASSNAME o1, YOUROBJECTCLASSNAME o2) {
            return Double.compare(o1.getdistance,o2.getdistance);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

please reduce radius to 500. your problem will be solved.